# How to restore and backup data in standalone mdf

Tags: c#, sql, mdf

I am developing a windows form application in c# visual studio 2010, where I want to create a feature in which a user is allowed to restore and backup the database by itself. The problem is that I am using a standalone mdf file.

i am using sql server express by attaching mdf file to the application, when i try to backup using query it's work but when i try restore the database using query it say that it's say that doesn't have permission to alter table. And then i try to using smo but it say that unable to open the file. So i am wondering if there is any option

Comment: Hope this article helps you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26390/SQL-Server-2005-Database-Backup-and-Restore-using

Comment: You need to describe you problem further and also write a bit about what you have tried so far.

Comment: r u using mysql database......?

Comment: mdf hints he is using SQL Server, and by standalone I would suspect he means SQL Server Express by attaching the mdf/ldf files. Just guessing, though

Comment: Did you want to allow the user to Backup/Restore database from Sql Server Management Console (from inside Sql)? Or just want to execute database backup command on Button Click or something similar?

Comment: @V.P.Verma, yes i want to restore by button click on the form

Comment: @udaya726, i have tried it but the database in the server is all temp db which is not allowed to be backup and restore

Answer (score 0):

To create a backup using t-sql you can use:

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks 
TO DISK = 'C:\BACKUP\AdventureWorks.bak'
GO
```

To restore use:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\BACKUP\AdventureWorks.bak'
GO
```

Add `WITH REPLACE` to replace the existing database.

You can fire those SQL commands using `ExecuteNonQuery`.

*Note:* this works on Standard SQL Server, but I have not used it on SQL Server Express with an attached database file.

Comment: i have try it but it is error "you do not have permission to alter database or the database is not exsists"

Comment: User does not have permission to alter database 'DatabaseA', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
ALTER DATABASE statement failed. -  -

Comment: it appear when i try to restore

Comment: If there are open connections to your database, you need to close them first. AKTER DATABASE will fail after a certain amount of time when there are open connections.

Comment: so do you mean i need to using another application to restore and backup it since its being used?